# jQuery Code on <td> with ajax to extract a column from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-table

I have a table of banned IPs. The first column holds the IPs, the second one has the timestamp and the third the action links. I want to make an ajax call when "Remove Ban" is clicked on the link. For that I need the IP address from the first column. But somehow, this isn't working.
Here are the codes (You can check it on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/yAm87/))

```
<tr>
    <td class="ip">192.168.1.1</td>
    <td class="centered">August 10, 2011</td>
    <td class="right action_td">
        <a class="action ban remove" href="javascript://">Remove Ban</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

(This is just a `<tr>`. Other elements of the table removed.)

The js:

```
$(".action.ban.remove").live('click', function(){ // remove ban
    ip = $(this).parent("td.right").siblings("td.ip").html();
    alert(ip);
});
```

Instead of 192.168.1.1, it alerts with "null". Am I doing it wrong?

***update*** okay, I figured out the problem. I had another handler attached to it which was creating the problem. Foolish of me. :-\

Comment: @Abhishek: Are you sure the HTML is well formed i.e. proper table closing tag etc? Check this jsfiddle post: http://jsfiddle.net/9xdpy/ first link works but not the second one (since the HTML element is not well formed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
ip = $(this).parent().siblings("td.ip").text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sRRn9/

Comment: It works if you wrap it with `table` tag, as pointed by @Joseph: http://jsfiddle.net/sRRn9/

Comment: Working. Had another handler attached to it. :-\

Answer (score 2):

Just needed a table element to wrap the table row. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S2YZK/).

Comment: I _do_ have a table tag wrapped around the code. There are several other `tr`s inside the `table` (removed them to make it simple). I also have `thead` tag. Is that the culprit?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.remove').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert($(this).parent().prev().prev().html()); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6VFm5/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".remove").live('click', function(){ // remove ban
    ip = $(this).parent("td.right").siblings("td.ip").html();
    alert(ip);
});
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FpbQ3/)

Comment: First, it's not working. Secondly, I have more anchor tags with `action` class, but this one is identified by `remove`. I guess in that case, I could use `$('.remove')`, if that worked.

Comment: Yes, you can use remove class.